# PHP not reading $_POST variables

Tags: php, forms, apache, post

I set up a new AMP stack on a laptop so I could do some work locally.  I am no expert in the mechanics of Apache or PHP behind the scenes, so I have a problem.  I have a form which collects information and posts it to be processed by a php file.  The html form and php processor both work fine on my live server, but on the laptop, the php script doesn't appear to be seeing the posted variables.

Here is how I define the processor program

```
<form method='POST' action='myprogram.php'>
```

Here is an example of how I am populating the variables

```
<input type='text' name='gw' size='8' value='65000'>Gross Weight
```

here is how I am submitting them

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit' name='B1'>
```

in the php, here is how I am defining them locally

```
$gw=$_POST[gw];
```

and finally, here is the error message I get for every single variable:

> "Notice: Use of undefined constant gw - assumed 'gw' in C:\Apache\htdocs\myprogram\myprogram.php on line 21"

Since the code works perfectly on my apache 2.2 server and not on the 2.4 that I just installed, I'm pretty sure that the problem is in either my apache or php configuration.  I've looked everywhere I can think of and can't find a directive that "turns on" this feature.  I'd sure love some help on this one, thanks in advance.

Jim

Comment: `$gw=$_POST['gw'];`.... when `gw` is a string literal, it should be in quotes (`'`)... otherwise PHP will believe it to be a constant (which it isn't), so it will tell you that it's an undefined constant

Comment: This is PHP's way of telling you that there is actually an error in your program, but only if you allow it to tell you by enabling error logging

Comment: Thank you!, and I'm sorry this took so long to get back to.  I added the single quotes and all is working fine.  That should teach me not to get in a hurry!

Answer (score 3):

$_POST values are stored in an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), that is to say the values are indexed by some type of string 'key'. To access an element, you must use the appropriate string:

```
$value = $_POST['gw']; // a string using single quotes
$key = 'gw';
$value = $_POST[$key]; // this is also acceptable
```

In your code, you did not include quotes around your string, so PHP interpreted it as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing are the quotes around `$gw=$_POST['gw']` It thinks that you are using a constant `gw`. Here is the specific article with regards to this error: [Why is $foo[bar] wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

For better code that doesn't produce errors I recommend using:

`$gw = ( empty($_POST['gw']) ) ? $_POST['gw'] : false;`

This is PHP's ternary operator. This code checks that there is in fact a value before assigning it to the variable.